# Proving that a polynomial $|P(x)|=e^x$ has a solution

Tags: calculus

> Prove that $|P(x)|=e^x$ has a solution.
>
> $|P(x)|$ is a polynomial (that isn't $0$) and $x\in \mathbb R$.

This is what I did:

$g(x)=|P(x)|-e^x$

Now there are several cases:

$g(0)=|P(0)|-1 \Rightarrow \begin{cases}
 |P(0)|>1 \rightarrow g(0)>0\\
 |P(0)|<1 \rightarrow g(0)<0\\
\end{cases}$

And there are similar cases for $g(1)$ with $\sum |P_i|>e$ but how can I use these cases with IVT ?

Comment: Look at large $\lvert x\rvert$

Comment: @DanielFischer You mean that for large enough x, $e^x$ will be bigger than the polynomial and there should be some x that makes the polynomial bigger than $e^x$?

Comment: Unclear: instead of "has a solution" you should say whether we are to find $P$ that satisfies this for all $x$, or whether we are to find $x$ that satisfies this for a given $P$, or what...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $P$ is a non-zero constant $c$ then $|P(x)|=e^x$ has the solution $x=\log |c|$. Suppose now that $P$ is not constant. This means that $\lim_{x \to \pm\infty} |P(x)|=\infty$. Therefore if you define $g(x)=|P(x)|-e^x$ then the limit of $g$ at $-\infty $ is $+\infty$ and the limit of $g$ at $+\infty$ is $-\infty$ (exponential grows faster).

Since $g$ is continuous, it has at least one zero.

Comment: How you "got rid" of all the Xs from the polynomial in $x=\log |c|$ ?

Comment: @GinKin: The polynomial is a constant in the first case.

Comment: Ah, like $P_0$. Thanks.

Comment: Isn't it neccessary to prove that $|P(x)|<e^x$ as $x\to\infty$ ? I mean we have here $\infty-\infty$ as $x\to\infty$

Comment: @GinKin: You can prove that the exponential grows faster. It is true that in this case we have an indetermination, but $P(x)/e^x$ goes to $0$, so we can write $e^x-P(x)=e^x(1-P(x)/e^x)$ which is not indeterminate anymore.